# How to display Linear Progress Indicator based on Total data And Used data in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have to display a Linear Progress Indicator based on Total data And Used data in Flutter.

I have a Class named ActivePlansModel as below.

```
ActivePlansModel currentPlan = ActivePlansModel();

class ActivePlansModel {
  String? planName;
  String? planType;
  String? validity;
  String? totalQuota;
  String? usedQuota;
  String? startDate;
  String? endDate;
  String? planStage;
  String? volQuotaUnit;

  static ActivePlansModel? fromHashMap(dynamic map) {
    if (map == null) return null;
    ActivePlansModel result = new ActivePlansModel();
    result.planName = map["planName"];
    result.planType = map["plangroup"];
    result.validity = map["validity"].toString();
    result.totalQuota = map["volTotalQuota"].toString();
    result.usedQuota = map["volUsedQuota"].toString();
    result.startDate = map["startDate"];
    result.endDate = map["expiryDate"];
    result.planStage = map["planstage"];
    result.volQuotaUnit = map["volQuotaUnit"];

    return result;
  }

  static List<ActivePlansModel> fromArrayOfHashMap(dynamic jsonArray) {
    List<ActivePlansModel> list = [];
    if (jsonArray != null) {
      for (var jsonObject in jsonArray) {
        list.add(fromHashMap(jsonObject)!);
      }
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

Here Class have `usedData` and `totalData`, So I have to display Linear Progress Indicator based on Total data And Used data.

Like the below Image.

[image]

So how can I create a Progress Bar?

Please help me,
Thank You.

Comment: 1) Select a Flutter "progress bar" widget you like (there are many to choose from!), 2) Add it to a [Stateful widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html), 3) wire in the code to update your progress bar.  Here's an example (one of many!): https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/flutter-progress-bar-b7df22199380

Answer (score 5):

You can use [LinearProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/LinearProgressIndicator-class.html) to display a Progress Bar. Set the `value` to update the progress indicator - this is a double, so you can apply something like `usedData/totalData` to fetch the percentage of the consumed data. There's a lot of samples out there to help you get started.

```dart
double _consumedData = usedData / totalData;

...

LinearProgressIndicator(
  value: _consumedData,
)
```